# How to turn off side switch in synergy?

Tags: synergy

How do I turn off side swapping in synergy? I don't want switch screen when my mouse moves to the sides.

Comment: The whole point of synergy is to switch machine when your mouse moves to the sides... Could you be more specific on your setup and on what your problem is?

Comment: I set it up so I switch with hotkeys. I want to switch screens with just hot keys so when I'm in a game it don't switch.

Comment: Try using ShareMouse http://www.share-mouse.com/ it'll allow you to set hotkey for switching to screen.

Answer (score 2):

If you move your extra displays to the far corners, you essentially remove all paths for the mouse to take, making it seem like mouse switching is disabled.

For example, here's my configuration: [image: here].

Answer (score 1):

One can't turn the feature off, but one can add a delay before it happens in the advanced settings tab on the server setup dialogue.

It's in milliseconds so set it to something high like 60000, and it'll need the cursor on the edge for a whole minute before attempting to switch.